# Max years allowed parameter for credit card field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in a rails application in c9. In my project I entered the credit card fields with this code at the end:

```
 <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: +15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"}%>
```

I get this error message: There are too many years options to be built. Are you sure you haven't mistyped something? You can provide the :max_years_allowed parameter.

How is this :max_years_allowed parameter written in code to bridge this problem? Any expert advice?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Are you sure about the "end_year: +15", shouldn't that be "end_year: Date.today.year + 15"?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my mistake and entered the following code as provided by Fallenhero: `enter code here`<%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"}%>. The problem is solved.